# Ansible user_module exit with "rc: -25" if UID is large

Tags: ansible, linux

Ansible [`user_module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) exit with `rc: -25` if trying to create user with UID provided from Active Directory (AD) domain controller (DC).

**main.yml**

```
- name: Configure local user for example.com
  user:
    name: example
    password: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/example_at_host.example.com') }}"
    system: yes         # Defaults to no
    createhome: yes     # Defaults to yes
    uid: '1234567890'   # Default user id of example
    group: '1234500513' # Default group "example users"
    groups: wheel       # Empty by default, here, provide root rights via sudoers wheel
    shell: /bin/bash    # Defaults to /bin/bash
    state: present
  when: ansible_domain == "example.com"
  tags: install,user
```

**stdout**

```
TASK [Configure local user for example.com] *****************************************************************************
fatal: [host.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: ''
  name: example
  rc: -25
```

Even if trying to create the user manually on CLI

```
useradd --system --create-home --uid 1234567890 --gid 1234500513 --groups wheel --shell /bin/bash --comment "Example User" example
```

it fails.

```
File size limit exceeded (core dumped)
```

How to resolve this and get user created with same ID as in AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research it turned out that it will be necessary to set a larger file size limit via Ansible module  [`pam_limits`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pam_limits_module.html). The file size limit should larger than UID * 292 bytes.

```
- name: Add or modify soft fsize limits for root domain (for /var/log/lastlog)
  pam_limits:
    domain: root
    limit_type: soft
    limit_item: fsize
    value: '360493823880' # uid * 292
  when: ansible_domain == "example.com"
  tags: install,user,system
```

**Credits to**

- [Is there a reason why `/var/log/lastlog` is a huge sparse file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530157/266568)
- [Red Hat Solution 3123941](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3123941)